# Executing "run" in the context of a sub project by default in 0.13.x

Tags: sbt

I used to be able to use the following in my `build.sbt` file to allow me to executed a `run` command while in my `root` project, but the run command would only run in the context of my `migrations` project:

```
lazy val root = project.dependsOn(rest,migrations).settings(publish := { }).disablePlugins(RevolverPlugin, AssemblyPlugin)
lazy val rest = project.enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin)
lazy val migrations = project.dependsOn(rest).settings(mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.myapp.Migrations"), fork in run := true).disablePlugins(RevolverPlugin)

run in Compile <<= (run in Compile in migrations)
```

I would then execute `run` like so:

```
> run up
```

(p.s. `up` is an argument to be passed to `com.myapp.Migrations`)

However, when updating to sbt v0.13.17 I now receive the warning:

```
See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html
run in Compile <<= (run in Compile in migrations)
```

In the referenced url, it seems to indicate that I can replace the `<<=` with `:=`, however if I change it like so:

```
run in Compile := (run in Compile in migrations)
```

And then I type in `run up` in sbt, I get the error:

```
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: run (similar: plugin, new)
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Expected '::'
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] run up
[error]    ^
```

Does anyone know how I can update the aforementioned line to be compliant with 0.13.x and still work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html#Migrating+with

> ### Migrating with InputKey
>
> When using InputKey instead of:
>
> ```
> run <<= docsRunSetting
> ```
>
> when migrating you mustn’t use .value but .evaluated:
>
> ```
> run := docsRunSetting.evaluated
> ```

In your case try `run in Compile := (run in Compile in migrations).evaluated`.